# Does isotretinoin increase your chance of colds and flus?

Tags: common-cold, influenza

1. For brevity, I'll use URTI to refer to both colds and flus. Is this medically correct?
2. My sister hasn't gotten a URTI in the past five years previously. But since 
   starting Epuris in Sep. 2018, her GP has diagnosed her with a URTI monthly. Is there any evidence that isotretinoin indirectly causes these URTI? Some unsubstantiated commmenters
   allege "yes":

> [Posted October 28, 2007](https://www.acne.org/forums/topic/174735-who-has-suffered-from-frequent-colds-while-on-accutane/?do=findComment&comment=2079580)
>
> Your body is under a lot of additional stress, which makes your body more prone to sickness. However, respiratory infections are something to take seriously when on Accutane, as they can be a side-effect. You should let your doctor know about this.
>
> [Posted August 26, 2009](https://www.acne.org/forums/topic/246559-getting-colds-and-other-illnesses-while-on-accutane/?do=findComment&comment=2695769)
>
> Yep, you got it accutane weakens the immune system....For some it persists after the course is over and for some it has gotten better of time after the course is over.
>
> [Posted August 27, 2009](https://www.acne.org/forums/topic/246559-getting-colds-and-other-illnesses-while-on-accutane/?do=findComment&comment=2696324)
>
> Oh my yes. I had bad colds throughout the course which is pretty unusual for me.

Comment: accutane can mess with your triglycerides and is believed to cause psychiatric issues also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, URTI includes common colds and flu but is not limited to them. It includes rhinitis (nose inflammation due to bacterial or viral infections), sinusitis (infection/inflammation of nasal sinuses), pharyngitis (sore throat) or laryngitis (mainly manifested as hoarse voice). Colds and flu may be presented as any of the upper manifestations.
2. According to [Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/sfx/isotretinoin-side-effects.html), which is a reliable source, nasopharyngitis is a common (1% to 10%) side effect of Isotretinoin.